# Как подключиться к коммутатору через ssh с помощью бибилиотеки Paramiko

Tags: python, ssh, switch, telnet, paramiko

Всем привет!

Есть идея осуществить подключение к коммутатору Cisco через ssh при помощи библиотеки Paramiko.

Данный скрипт нашел на просторах интернета:

```
import paramiko

host = '5.251.4.102'
user = 'admin'
secret = '00000'
port = 22

client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect(hostname=host, username=user, password=secret, port=port, look_for_keys=False, allow_agent=False)
stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('show running')
data = stdout.read() + stderr.read()
client.close()
```

Коммутатор полностью настроен, у меня есть логин и пароль.
Не пойму как это сделать.
Еще проблема в том как понять что скрипт нормально отработал, ведь в вышеуказанном коде мы только зашли на коммутатор ничего не скачивали и не изменяли ?
Пробовал гуглить, инфы много, но то ли мне попадаются не те сайты то ли я понять не могу что там написано.

Comment: Пока что непонятно, что именно вы хотите сделать. Вот подключились вы к коммутатору - и что дальше вам нужно?

Comment: Мне это нужно для того чтобы после того как я подключусь к коммутатору я смог скопировать в папку на рабочем столе файлы конфигурации коммутатора

Comment: Ну, в таком случае, вы посылаете в терминал *show running config* и ждете, пока вам не придет приглашение коммутатора и перевод строки

Comment: ну вы же считали в переменную data что-о своим скриптом. Теперь вывдете ее на печать, например.

Answer (score 0):

```
from netmiko import ConnectHandler
cisco = {
"device_type": "cisco_ios",
"host": "5.251.4.102",
"username": "admin",
"password": "00000",
"secret": "00000",# Секретный ключ для входа в режим enable !!!!
}

net_connect = ConnectHandler(**cisco) #Осуществляем подключение к устройству,
# установилось SSH соединение.


net_connect.enable()# Вход в режим enable.
net_connect.find_prompt()
net_connect.send_command("copy show running config tftp://14.2.074.098") # Этой    командой мы копируем файлы конфигурации на tftp-сервер.
```